# is there any way,that i can use line break in list<String>

Tags: list

I have a empty list and iam adding various data,,the thing is all the values showing in one line only,so can i use line break in list

```
public list<String> strsss=new list<String>();
strsss.add('Name'+'BillingCity');
```

this will be output as **Name BillingCity**
I want it as

```
  Name
  BillingCity
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "output as"? Can you post code that would output that?

Comment: if i return my list,it shows ,e above output

Comment: Please tell where you want to use it. You can put new line character in string, but it can behave differently (& at times unpredictably ) depending on where its used.

Answer (score 0):

Much of this depends on where and how you're outputting your code. But yes, you could put a newline character in following the Name using `\n`. That can be done via Apex.

As I recall, not all text strings will support all characters for storage. A long text string will support a new line character but a 255 character or less text string won't. Inside of Apex, any string will support it, but when you go to save it to a field, there could be an issue is what sticks in my mind. You'd need to give it a try. How it displayed would be dependent on the formatting of how you were to output your text.

Comment: fields of type `Text Area` and `Text Area (long)` support new line

Comment: Right! That's what I was thinking, that it had to be a text area, but didn't phrase it quite that way. Thanks for the helping me clarify it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming this only to display. if yes,

Option 1:

```
List<String> cityList = new List<String>();
for(Account acc : [select ..from account]) {
  cityList.add('name');
  cityList.add(acc.billingcity);
}
```

Option 2:

```
public List<String> cityList {get;set;}
public String name='name';
String
for(Account acc : [select..from account]) {
cityList.add(acc.billingcity);
}
```

//vf page

```
<apex:repeat value="cityList" var="city">
    <apex:outputText value="{!name}"/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!city}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public list<String> strsss=new list<String>(); 
strsss.add('Name\n'+'BillingCity');
```

Try this. It will work.

Comment: How do you know it will work when the op has not provided usage context

Comment: Please read the question and the answer provided